# Custom NuGet package not installing in wix project

Tags: nuget, wix

I generate a NuGet that is is just a number of redist files that I want to use in one of my projects. If I install it in a C# or C++ projects, it works. But when I try to install it in a wixproj project and I get the following message:
*Could not install package 'package-1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Unsupported,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

I generate the package through a TeamCity task (using NuGet 5.6.0). When trying to generate the package with a NuGet CLI 5.8.1, I get the following warning:

*WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:

- Add a dependency group for native0.0 to the nuspec*

Looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5128, one of the solutions was trying a dependencies group targetFramework, (I used "native0.0") with no success.  My nuspec is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <package>
  <metadata>
    <id>package</id>

    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>package</authors>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>my package</description>
    <copyright>© 2021 company, Inc</copyright>
    <tags>native</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="downloads\Folder\win32.vs2017\file1.lib" target="lib\native\lib\win32.vs2017\" />
    <file src="downloads\Folder\win32.vs2017\file1-debug.lib" target="lib\native\lib\win32.vs2017\" />
    <file src="downloads\Folder\Include\**" target="lib\native\include\" />
    <file src="build\package.props" target="build\native" />
  </files>
</package>
```

And my props file

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <MyVersion>1.0.0</MyVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can install other NuGet packages into wixprojects, so how I configure mine to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it, the issue lies at the line

```
    <file src="build\package.props" target="build\native" />
```

changing target to `"build\"` allows the NuGet to be loaded to any project type, included WixProj. Note that the NU5128 warning still exists though, but not an issue for me.